# DOM Tree Manipulation (document.createElement) code reuse

Tags: javascript, html, dom, domdocument, createelement

So basically, I've run into this problem enough times that it is seriously frustrating me.

What I'd like to do is have code like this:

```
node = document.createElement("option");
textbox = document.createTextNode(currentday.getFullYear() + i);
node.value = currentday.getFullYear() + i;
node.appendChild(textbox);
document.getElementById("pick_up_year").appendChild(node);
document.getElementById("return_year").appendChild(node);
```

But this code only appends the nodes to return_year (a select element, obviously).

It DOES work if I repeat the code like this:

```
node = document.createElement("option");
textbox = document.createTextNode(currentday.getFullYear() + i);
node.value = currentday.getFullYear() + i;
node.appendChild(textbox);
document.getElementById("pick_up_year").appendChild(node);
node = document.createElement("option");
textbox = document.createTextNode(currentday.getFullYear() + i);
node.value = currentday.getFullYear() + i;
node.appendChild(textbox);
document.getElementById("return_year").appendChild(node);
```

But that's hardly elegant, is it? Why am I forced to reuse code and is there an easy way around this?

The HTML is basically this:

```
<select id="pick_up_days" name="pick_up_day">
    <option value="nojs">Please enable JavaScript</option>
</select>
<select id="pick_up_year" name="pick_up_year">
    <option value="nojs">Please enable JavaScript</option>
</select>
```

Comment: A node can only have one parent. Upon the first append, `node` is inserted into the document tree in the subtree of the specified `<option>` `Element` node. Upon the second append, `node` is moved to the subtree of the specified `<select>` `Element` node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with [cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.cloneNode)

```
document.getElementById("pick_up_year").appendChild(node);
document.getElementById("return_year").appendChild(node.cloneNode(true));
```

Comment: If `node` is a `Text` node, there's no need to set the `deep` parameter of `Node::cloneNode` to `true`.

Comment: But we know here that node is not a Text node, besides that, the MDN docs state that the parameter must be present for older browsers.

Comment: Sorry; that's a faux pas on my part. I meant to imply that `deep` should be `false` for a `Text` node, but `node` was an `Element` node.